# How to set authorization header and protect routes in Vuejs and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, jwt, passport.js

I am using passport-jwt strategy to protect auth users in my app, once I login I am generating a `jwt-token` now I want to protect my welcome page rout so that user cannot open it without login

So when I login I am creating `jwt-token` with `payload` like this

my user.js file

```
const payload = { email: rows[0].email } // jwy payload
            console.log('PAYLOAD')
            console.log(payload)
            jwt.sign(
                payload,
                key.secretOrKey, { expiresIn: 3600 },
                (err, token) => {
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        token: 'Bearer ' + token,
                        email
                    })

                })
```

Now in my passport.js I am doing like this

```
   const opts = {};

opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey;

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {

    let payLoadEmail = jwt_payload.email //payload data what I have passed in creating jwt 
    console.log("payload email :" + payLoadEmail)
    User.fetchLogedInUser(payLoadEmail)
        .then(([rows]) => {
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                return done(null, rows[0].email) // returning data what I need
            }
            return done(null, false)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

}));
```

Both are working fine.

Now I want to protect my welcome rout so in my router.js file

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport')


const UsersCtrl = require('../controllers/users');

router.use('/login', UsersCtrl.login)
router.use('/welcome',passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}))
router.use('/logout', UsersCtrl.logout)


module.exports = router;
```

suppose user types `localhost:8080/welcome` without login then I want to protect it

So in my store.js file when user logs in I am doing this on login click and I have made a method `getAuthUser`. I don't know how to I pass this config to protect my welcome file

Here is my full store.js code

```
    import axios from 'axios'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

function checkTokenValidity(token) {  // token validity
    if (token) {
        const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token)
        return decodedToken && (decodedToken.exp * 1000) > new Date().getTime()

    }
    return false
}
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        user: null,
        isAuthResolved: false   // this I am calling on my login page i am confused where should I call this or not to call this
    },
    getters: {
        authUser(state) {
            return state.user
        },
        isAuthenticated(state) {
            return !!state.user
        }
    },
    actions: {
        loginWithCredentials({ commit }, userDate) {
            return axios.post('/api/v1/users/login', userDate)
                .then(res => {
                    const user = res.data
                    console.log(user.email)
                    localStorage.setItem('jwt-token', user.token)
                    commit('setAuthUser', user)
                })
        },

        logout({ commit }) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                localStorage.removeItem('jwt-token')
                commit('setAuthUser', null)
                resolve(true)
            })

        },

        getAuthUser({ commit, getters }) {
            const authUser = getters['authUser']
            const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt-token')
            const isTokenValid = checkTokenValidity(token)
            if (authUser && isTokenValid) {
                return Promise.resolve(authUser)
            }

            const config = {  // here what to do with this how can I pass this to protect my route
                headers: {
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            }

        }

    },
    mutations: {
        setAuthUser(state, user) {
            return state.user = user
        },
        setAuthState(state, authState) {
            return state.isAuthResolved = authState
        }
    }
```

In my route.js vue file

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import store from './store'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
        path: '/welcome',
        name: 'welcome',
        meta: { onlyAuthUser: true },
        component: () =>
            import ('./views/Welcome.vue'),


    }, ]
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    store.dispatch('auth/getAuthUser')
        .then((authUser) => {
            const isAuthenticated = store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']

            if (to.meta.onlyAuthUser) {
                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    next()
                } else {
                    next({ name: 'PageNotAuthenticated' })
                }
            } else if (to.meta.onlyGuestUser) {
                if (isAuthenticated) {
                    next({ name: 'welcome' })
                } else {
                    next()
                }
            } else {
                next()
            }
        })
})

export default router
```

My main problem is I want to protect routes and make the user authenticated using jwt and passport I am getting jwt once I login and want to check once my protected rout is access with out login for backend.

In front end (vue.js) I my store file in action> `getAuthUsers` I don't know how to pass config to other routes like my welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question entirely because you seem to be implementing route access correctly. You simply need to add routes as an array while the rest of your code remains the same.

```
const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
        path: '/welcome',
        name: 'welcome',
        meta: { onlyAuthUser: true },
        component: () =>
            import ('./views/Welcome.vue'),


    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        meta: { onlyGuesUser: true },
        component: () =>
            import ('./views/Login.vue'),


    }]
})
```

For using `Authentication: Bearer xxxxxxxx` you can modify your `axios` code to directly use required headers instead of passing it through routes every time. Make a new folder called `services` and a file called `base-api`. You can obviously name it however you like, but this is my setup.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default () => {
  let headers = {
    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
  };
  let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('jwt-token');
  if (accessToken && accessToken !== '') {
     headers.Authorization = accessToken;

  };
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: 'SECRET_URL_',
    headers: headers
  });
}
```

Import this file in your `store.js`. Replace `import axios from 'axios'` with `import axios from '@src/services/base-api.js`. As the file is returning an axios instance you need to access it as `axios()`. Which means you function would be

```
return axios().post('/api/v1/users/login', userDate)
                .then(res => {
                    // do whatever
                })
```

Comment: hey in you base-api.js `headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${jwt-token}`;` in place of Bearer${jwt-token}   I can pass simplly like this  `headers.Authorization = `accessToken `  because I am geting token in Bearer prefix already?

Comment: Ya its entirely up to you, I added a word for demonstration purposes on how to further edit the headers.

Comment: hey what url should I pass here in base-api.js   `baseURL: 'SECRET_URL_',`

Comment: Well you are doing `axios.post('/api/v1/users/login', userDate)` so lets say the actual url is `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/login` then you would pass `http://localhost:8000/` as the base url.